# How to get original value of cookie when use encryption key

Tags: cakephp, cookies, encryption

I am using

```
public function beforeFilter() {
   parent::beforeFilter();
   //$this->Cookie->name='cookie_test'; 
   //$this->Cookie->time=3600; 
   //$this->Cookie->path=''; 
   //$this->Cookie->domain=''; 
   //$this->Cookie->secure=false; 
   //$this->Cookie->key='39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5'; 
   //$this->Cookie->httpOnly=true; >
}
```

for setting cookie but it get in encryption form when I try to read this.

Comment: please don't change the format of the php script. the way you are written it is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to write this function. you can delete it completely.

and when you set your Cookie. what ever you write it should give you the value on read.

e.g. if you write

```
$this->Cookie->write('name', 'Larry');
```

when you reading it by

```
$this->Cookie->read('name');
```

it gives you "Larry"

Comment: I am use $this->Cookie->key = '39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5'; for encryption key and set $this->Cookie->write('log_cookie', 'CTCGQckDZcA+IiRRQPebZr5ElDQ='); and i am get an array by using $this->Cookie->read('log_cookie'), which have Array ( [Ð2¡à›Ô®š7Öi÷] => ž2òÔ™û† )
How to get this value as original value

Comment: you are using "," after $this->Cookie->read('log_cookie') use ";" semicolon $this->Cookie->read('log_cookie');

Comment: No i am use ";"(semicolon) and the value show in encryption form

Comment: did you change any thing on your config files?

Comment: No, i didn't change anything in config. But if i am not use  $this->Cookie->key = '39lbkutg1i2l0kta6785d8qki5'; the i am get original value of cookie

Comment: Trust me that doesn't matter. you don't need to use key.

Comment: Okk Isaac Rajaei and thanks again...........
We meet again with another problem :)